# Attaching schema to Meteor.users

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to customise my Meteor.users schema:

```
Schema.users = new SimpleSchema({
username: {
    type: String,
},
test:{
    type: String,
},
services: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
}
});
```

And when I call:

```
Accounts.createUser({username:"lionel",test:"123",password:"123"});
```

Console returned:

```
Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: Test is required
......
Sanitized and reported to the client as: Test is required [400]
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Accounts.createUser()` expects extra info to come across in a `profile` key.

Use:

```
Accounts.createUser({username:"lionel",password:"123",profile: {test:"123"}});
```

And set up an `Accounts.onCreateUser()` function on the server:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile) user.test = options.profile.test;
  return user;
});
```

[docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just added onCreateUser function, adjust "test" to profile in my schema, and I am sure onCreateUser function is triggered. But still my db shows empty profile field.

Comment: Here's result from db

{
    "_id" : ......,
    "createdAt" : .......,
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            ......
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ 
                {
                    "when" : ......,
                    "hashedToken" : ......
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "username" : ......,
    "profile" : {}
}

Comment: Sorry, forgot options.profile.test and not options.test